# I cannot install libtool on my pc

Tags: 20.04

When am trying to install it tells me unable to fetch archives,maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1470406/edit) to show us actual, complete input and output. Accurate details are best, do not summarize.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`